# What are these strange shades in the BGE?

Tags: game-engine, shaders, normals

[image]

[image]

What are these strange shades in the BGE and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshots, this looks like a problem with the normals of your mesh.

In editmode, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to make normals consistent to see if that solves your problem.